# What are advantages of using WebDriver over IDE?

Tags: ide, webdriver

I am new to Selenium and have spent about a week using IDE. So far, so good. However, some other parts of our application involve heavy drag-n-drop capabilities, and I'm not so sure about that...which brings me to my question...what type of specific things can WebDriver do that the IDE cannot do? I read the Selenium front page, and know that WebDriver can make more "robust" tests, but I'm not entirely clear what robust means in this context? Longer? More capabilities?

What I'm looking for is what type of particular tests could be run with WebDriver that couldn't be run in the IDE? And are any of them related to drag-n-drop? This will inform my decision about whether to keep on using the IDE or to switch over. I think it's better to use something from the beginning than to create a lot of tests and then switch over.

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the full features of your chosen language. For example, using the IDE you are stuck to using the IDE's API, however if you choose to use the WebDriver explicitly you can combine it with C# and use C#'s full features (such as LINQ).

A few of the IDE commands are not directly converted with the WebDriver.

You can integrate a pure WebDriver test into a CI (Continuous Integration) server.

It is not limited to just Firefox, whereas the IDE is (since the IDE is only available in Firefox).

You can improve and extend Selenium more easily. For example using Extension methods and inheritance. (For instance, extending Selenium so that whenever it cannot find an element, it takes a screenshot of the page)

It will be more robust, as the IDE will not always give you the most reliable way of finding an element. For instance, if the element you require is nested within a table, the XPath that the IDE will give you will infer directly to specific table rows and cells.

For instance something like this:

```
//table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[3]/a[1]/b
```

Is not the most reliable XPath in the world. Those without any knowledge of XPath or automated testing or how Selenium works, will stick with that and then waste hours figuring out why this XPath query fails. Others will change it, and just use the XPath as a base query.

The IDE should usually be used for those who don't have much programming knowledge (e.g some testers), if you want your developers and/or the test developer's to use Selenium, go directly with the WebDriver. It will feel more like programming with a fully-fledged language instead of scripting (after all, the scripts that the IDE generates are purely HTML files). The idea is generally for those who don't have much programming knowledge to simply hit 'play' and let Selenium do the work.

Drag-and-drop are applicable within the IDE and WebDriver.

Most of the development in Selenium (it seems) goes into extending the WebDriver code, the IDE may be left behind in some new features.

Using WebDriver directly, you can also use the full features of a unit testing framework (usually NUnit with C# or Junit/TestNG for Java). This allows things like repeating tests for each browser (i.e repeating tests in Chrome, Firefox and IE) or defining certain logic before and after tests (i.e adding user memberships, creating users, setting up other test data).

Fellow developers might be more inclined to help out if it is using a programming language as opposed to a scripting language (ie WebDriver is programmed in a programming language, the IDE scripts are just HTML files). Putting it in your solution and having it as part of the nightly build process helps to ensure developers help out in your tests progression.

Thinking about it, another example is a bug is fixed but introduces a new bug which causes your test to fail. Who's responsibility is it to fix the test? You or them? Having it use WebDriver directly, they can just look up the source code to Selenium and figure out the API usage themselves. With the IDE, it is literally a HTML file that calls some javascipt. Not much documentation on it.

To sum up: if you don't have much programming experience, either learn a language and use WebDriver with it directly, or just stick with the IDE. Either will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

IDE cannot be used for serious automation. I would sussgest learn the API and use it with Java/C#/Python. It will help you churn out some good automation and will payback really well.

You can always use the IDE to learn how the code is generated.